# Change AssemblyName Based on Localized CFBundleDisplayName with Xamarin.Mac

Tags: xamarin, localization, visual-studio-mac, xamarin.mac, localizable.strings

> Update:
>
> Now it's an approved bug fo Xamarin.Mac. You can contribute from here:
>   https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/7466

I coded a Xamarin.Mac app. I localized my app bundle name and bundle display name via InfoPlist.strings inside of "lproj" folders
with the help of Xcode.
[image]

Localized bundle name is visible on menu via app name now:
[image]

However, unlike Xamarin.iOS, Xamarin.Mac gets app Dock name from Assembly Name in Project options, not from "CFBundleDisplayName" :

[image]

So, my app name on the Dock icon could not response the localization settings, it stays unchanged.

[image]

So the important thing is:
How can I localize the "Assembly Name" in app options for Visual Studio Mac ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: macOS uses the app name (it knows nothing about Xamarin's assembly name), rename the app, the Dock and Switcher will update.

Comment: Yes, it is correct. But how can I localize it ? Creating a installer .pkg with app not allowed it @SushiHangover. Native Swift app can do it but Xamarin.Mac fails.